# Inkwell propagate tap events to parent

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using an `InkWell` widget for its `onLongPress` behaviour and the splash/ripple effect.

I hoped that if I didn't provide a `onTap` callback, it would ignore tap events or at least propagate them to the parent widget, however that is unfortunately not the case.

`GestureDetector` does give me the ability to have translucent hit tests, but it comes at the cost of losing the ripple animation

Is there an easy way to achieve the ripple effect, whilst also having a translucent touch behaviour on normal taps, or will I have to write my own InkWell alternative?

Comment: cannot you use `Listener` in the parent?

Comment: wrap `InkWell` inside `Material` widget. This may solve your issue.

Comment: @psking I could, GestureDetector would work too, however I do want the visual feedback InkWell provides

Comment: i mean `Listener` in the parent: `class FooInkWell extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Listener(
onPointerDown: print,
onPointerUp: print,
child: Material(
child: InkWell(
onTap: () => print('InkWell onTap'),
),
)
);
}
}`

Comment: @pskink Unfortunately not, in my case I have two nested `InkWell`s, one handling onTap and the child handling onLongPress. Tapping on the child widget doesn't propagate the onTap event to the parent (even though I haven't passed any callbacks)

Comment: why do you need two `InkWell`s if it can present a visual response for `onTap` only, not for `onLongPress`?

Comment: My usecase is being able to tap on a card (Blue rectangle) to view a post, and long press on an image inside the card to preview it in a larger format (red rectangle)
https://i.imgur.com/IFauq8w.png  I'd like to provide a visual response of inkwell on the red rectangle when you hold it down, but propagate the effect to the parent card if you tap it